# I don't know the syntax error I am doing in the program given :

Tags: java, if-statement, syntax-error

Task
Given an integer, , perform the following conditional actions:

If N is odd, print Weird
If N is even and in the inclusive range of  to , print Not Weird
If N is even and in the inclusive range of  to , print Weird
If N is even and greater than , print Not Weird
Complete the stub code provided in your editor to print whether or not  is weird.

program:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Solution {
    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = scanner.nextInt();
        
        if(N = odd){
            System.out.println("Weird");
        } else if(N = even ; 2 < N < 5) {
            System.out.println("Not Weird");
        } else if(N = even ; 6<N<20 ) {
            System.out.println("Weird");
        } else{
            System.out.println("Not Weird");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `odd`?  And why are you **assigning** it to `N` - `N = odd` is assignment, comparison would be `==`

Comment: Where are you getting syntax error ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use modulo `%`to check if a number is odd or even. Then use a logical AND `&&` for the if conditions.

```java
    if(N%2 == 1){
        System.out.println("Weird");
    } else if(2 < N && N < 5) {
        System.out.println("Not Weird");
    } else if(6 < N && N < 20) {
        System.out.println("Weird");
    } else{
        System.out.println("Not Weird");
    }
```